# How to replace "," with ""? How can I delete the comma in my values?

Tags: python, replace, attributeerror

I mean I have a column named **num_students**.

datatype of it is **object** and for example its written as 2,435

I want to get it as 2435 as object

What im trying to do is:

- timesData is the dataframe, num_students is column

`timesData.num_students = [ each.replace(",","") for each in timesData.num_students]`

I get error : 
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'replace'

Comment: so, you want it to be an integer type column, basically. Use - ```timesData.num_students = timesData.num_students.str.replace(',', '').astype('int')```

Comment: @CavinDsouza yeah but there is comma there. When i try to make it integer while there is comma in value, wont be a problem? it gives 
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '20,152'

Comment: edited my previous comment

Comment: Is the comma in the *value*, or merely added as part of the display?

Comment: its in the value @Prune

Comment: it gave an error again, ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer
@CavinDsouza, should i just restart my jupyter notebook? i dont know why it gives error

Comment: @Semih so basically, the column also contains null, hence converting the column to an `integer` type is not possible, it needs to either be left as `object` after the replace, or converted to `float` using `.astype('float')`

Comment: it works now! thanks a lot. why can we change it to float but not to int? it would write 0.0 as float, and 0 as integer, so why doesnt it convert Sir? @CavinDsouza

Comment: It is basically pandas' inability, rather numpy's inability to represent NA's in integer arrays. It can represent NA's in numeric arrays or floating-point arrays. Here's a good [read](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/gotchas.html#support-for-integer-na)

Comment: thank you so much for the explanation @CavinDsouza, i want to accept your answer as most helpful, but i guess you should reply it like other person did? otherwise im not able to choose your answer.. :)

Comment: @Semih No problem, I am new to SO, learning gradually. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it using `str.replace`,

```
timesData['num_students'] = timesData['num_students'].str.replace(',', '')
```

> str.replace(',', '') replaces the comma with nothing